# set unique key in v-for loop

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I'm working with `BootstrapVue`.

How can I set a unique `id` each time I'm inputing a new object to my template?

I've just tried to show it in my template (here: `{{????}}`) to see if its working but only output I get is `#`

Thanks in advance!

```
<template>
  <div>
    <div v-for="idInput in inputs" :key="idInput._id">
      <b-form-input class="col-md-6"></b-form-input>#
      {{????}}
    </div>

    <b-button @click="addInput()">Add Input</b-button>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    methods: {
      addInput() {
        this.inputs.push({});
      }
    },

    data() {
      return {
        inputs: [{}],
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

Comment: try using index in your v-for and use it as the id!

Comment: Please make the question more clear of what exactly you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: Hello, but when I use the index as my ID and will delete somthing in the future the ID will be reactive.. but I need it unique..

Comment: Well there are several things that you are not saying in your question. Where are you getting the objects from? DB? Or are you generating them in the for loop? If so then you can an MD5 hash over the object to get a unique id or anything you like ... but it is not really clear what you are trying to do ...

Answer (score 4):

Use the v-for index parameter, this should give you a unique index for each element.

Try it like this:

```
<div v-for="(idInput, index) in inputs" :key="index">
  <b-form-input class="col-md-6"></b-form-input>#
  {{index}}
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can replace to h2 to anything that you want to give a dynamic Id.
Here is my solution (based on an example with h2 element) :

```html
<template>
<div >

 <div v-for="(idInput,index) in inputs" :key="index">
      <b-form-input class="col-md-6"></b-form-input>#
      <h2 :id="idInput._id">{{idInput.text}}</h2>
    </div>

</div>
</template>
<script>

export default {

  data() {
      return {
        inputs: [{"_id":"first_id","text":"Bobby has"},
        {"_id":"second_id","text":"a good taste"},
         {"_id":"third_id","text":"for frameworks!"}]
      }
    },
  
}


  
</script>
<style>
#first_id {
  color:black;
}
#second_id {
  color:red;
}
#third_id {
  color: yellow;

}
</style>
```

Comment: I did not downvote ... , but out of curiosity why would you introduce an h2 element here? _id should be unique as I understood the OP? Also they want to push this into the array as far as I can see ... so your implementation is a bit strange ... that is why some would downvote this ...

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I thought he wanted an element whom's id was generated by the v-for. While he was only asking for a unique key value each time. Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: To be honest, the question should be flagged cause it is not 100% clear what the OP is asking ...